# Is the function sending a sentence to the diagonal of a sentence form extended over it, computable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, computability, incompleteness

> Is, the following function $h$ computable?

Let $h: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N $ be the function defined by:$$h(\ulcorner s \urcorner) = \ulcorner D(E_s(v)) \urcorner$$

for each sentence $s$ in the language of theory $T$, and $h(n)=0$ otherwise.

Where $E_s(v)$, called the extended sentence form of $s$, is the sentence form:

$\forall x \forall y \, (\operatorname {Proof}_T(x,v) \land [y= \min z: \operatorname {Proof}_T(z, \ulcorner s \urcorner)] \to x \geq y)$

and $D(E_s(v))$ is the diagonal formula of the sentence form $E_s(v)$, defined (along lines given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma#Proof)) by:

$\forall v (\mathcal G_f (^o\ulcorner \forall v (\mathcal G_f (k, v ) \to E_s(v)) \urcorner, v ) \to E_s(v))$

Where $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is the function defined by: $$ f(\ulcorner \mathcal A \urcorner)= \, \ulcorner A(^o\ulcorner A \urcorner) \urcorner $$, for any sentence form $A$ in the language of $T$, and $f(n)=0$ otherwise.

This question is connected to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4748706/489784) posting. So, the rationale is that if this is correct, then there would be a formula $\mathcal G_h(x,y)$ representing $h$ in theory $T$. Namely:

$\vdash_T \forall y \, (\mathcal G_h( ^o\ulcorner s \urcorner, y) \to y= \, ^o \ulcorner D(E_s(v)) \urcorner)$

and then we can define the sentence form $remote(x)$ as:

$\textbf{Define: } \\\begin{align} remote(x) \iff \exists y \exists z \exists u: \ & \mathcal G_h(x,y) \land \\& z=\min n: \operatorname {Proof}_T(n, x) \land \\&  u=\min m : \operatorname {Proof}_T(m, y) \land \\& u < z \end{align}$

I personally think that $h$ is computable, but I'm not sure. The reason why I think it is, because it appears to me that there is an exact syntactical way of producing $D(E_s(v))$ from $s$, so there must be an algorithm capturing it. However, I'm not sure if the underpinnings of Gödel's numbering assignment of the syntax may be incompatible with that?

Comment: atleast to  me it seems, h should be semi-computable (semi-decidable) , cuz for a given sentence s , h gives godel number of the sentence - " the smallest proof of s is smaller than or equal to any proof of this sentence  "                        if T is consistent , then there would be sentences where the smallest proof do not exist in T....